# Monitoring an element witch changable ID

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script that sends you a sound notification if something is changed within a DOM structure of an HTML element. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and am looking for some help.

[Here's the element that I want to monitor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkYys.png) Problem is that I have no idea how to "select" this element with javascript since it has the changeable ID (the numbers after RenderReport_ are changing every time you refresh this element) and the Class attribute is referring to other elements that don't interest me. Any ideas on how to handle it?

Comment: It's very likely possible to select it based on structure without referring to ID. Without knowing the structure of the page, it's very hard to say what will uniquely identify it. Here is an idea, though - how did *you* find it? You can refine the criteria from there and identify what you need to tell JS to look for.

Comment: Add a custom class to it then refer to that class. That is if you can modify the dom.

Comment: It maybe a good idea to share your code piece for an element that you can identify successfully, and point to the part that would cause an issue for you while identifying the DIV element shown in the linked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the element via its (unique!) parent element and then retrieve the desired element via `children` and index. In your case this would be

```
document.querySelector('#dropzone1').children[1]
```

But you need to make sure that the DOM structure always looks like this. For example, If there's a child added before, the index is not valid anymore.

Hope that helps!